# Git complains about merge conflict, but mergetool merges files automatically

Tags: git, merge, mergetool

I got a merge conflict:

> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in css/styles.less

But when I run `git mergetool`, the mergetool is able to automatically merge the files, without conflict. (My mergetool is Visual Studio.) Both versions of the file were changed, but all changes were on different lines, so I expected git to be able to merge the changes automatically (like the mergetool did).

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Did you commited the merge?

Comment: I didn't accidentally commit and hide the problem, if that's what you mean. I'm sure the that the mergetool did the merge, and it did it correctly. I'm surprised that git failed to do so.

Comment: I mean: After you called `git mergetool` and it merged automatically, did you commited the merge? Or is your question just a general question about why git is not able to merge it automatically?

Comment: It's a general question about why git didn't merge automatically. I committed without problem after merging :)